# `d` specifier in `ignore_tkr` directive

Tags: fortran, gfortran, flang

I have this old code

```
module foo
    interface
      subroutine bar(A)
        !dir$ ignore_tkr(trd) A
        DOUBLE COMPLEX, DIMENSION(*) :: A
      end subroutine
    end interface
end module foo
```

This is compiled fine by nvfortan and gfortran compilers. Yet, LLVM Flang cannot even parse it, because it doesn't know what `d` in the `ignore_tkr` means.

I assume, it means "ignore dimension". But I couldn't google anything up about it.

Could someone please send something to read about it and/or explain in details this thing?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. I also suggest to read [ask] and [mcve]. You should always include the *complete error message*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler directives are compiler specific. Note that for a standard Fortran compiler without any extensions they are just comments and will be ignored. The fact that it compiles with many compilers may just mean that those compilers ignore that directive altogether.

Some compilers will understand

```
!DIR$
```

other will understand

```
!DEC$
```

or

```
!GCC$
```

Gfortran, for example. has no obligation to understand directives specific to other compilers and will just ignore the directive you have shown.

---

For example, gfortran understand these directives https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GNU-Fortran-Compiler-Directives.html

For directives supported by Flang, consult the documentation https://releases.llvm.org/12.0.0/tools/flang/docs/Directives.html

---

Note that `!dir$ ignore_tkr (tkr) var-list` *is* supported by Flang and will omit checking the type, kind and/or rank of arguments passed to the procedure.

You specify the desired checks in the `(tkr)`. You use all of `t`, `k`, and `r` if you want to disable all three. The letter `d` is not among the possible letters to use and hence is erroneous. If you want to disable the checks for the number of dimensions of the array, use `r` for **rank**.

**Rank** is the correct word that is used for the number of dimensions of an array in the Fortran standard.

The same syntax holds for nvfortran, see section 4.4 in https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/archive/20.7/compilers/pdf/hpc207ref.pdf The only admissible parameters are `t`, `k` or `r`. No, `d` is not allowed. It does not mean anything in this context for these compilers.

The programmer may have used `d` instead of `r` inadvertently and the nvfortran compiler may ignore that or may even silently convert that to `d`. Such behaviour would only be specific to that compiler. I would just convert the `d` into `r` if it makes sense in that context.

> 4.4.1. `IGNORE_TKR` Directive Syntax
> The syntax for the `IGNORE_TKR` directive is this:
> `!DIR$ IGNORE_TKR [ [(<letter>) <dummy_arg>] ... ]`
> `<letter>` is one or any combination of the following:
> T – type
> K – kind
> R – rank
> For example, KR indicates to ignore both kind and rank rules and
> TKR indicates to ignore the type, kind, and rank arguments

Comment: Basically, I know most of what you described. Probably, I wasn't clear enough. I was interested what letter `d` means. Maybe it's documented in some compiler docs or somewhere else. I know that is a non-standard extension, yet I interested why it exists, what does it mean, etc..

Comment: It does not mean anything in that compiler. That is why it does not compile. I thought I was clear enough.

Comment: I have an old codebase that I need to compile with flang. It can be compiled with both nvfortran and gfortran. So I'd like to know what it means.

Comment: It does not mean anything!!! If your code is broken, you will have to fix it. The only admissible letters are t, k, r. There is nothing more to say.  Nvfortran only recognizes these three, gfortran ignores the directive altogether. I repeat: It does not mean anything.

Comment: So, how I'm able to compile it with nvfortran then if it doesn't recognize the `d` letter? :D

Comment: Why do you think that gfortran just ignores it?

Comment: You will get it to compile by flang by removing the `d` letter. Possibly exchanging it by `r` deending on the intent of the programmer.

Comment: Gfortran only recognizes directives marked by `!GCC$` as indicated by my answer. It has the `ATTRIBUTES NO_ARG_CHECK` directive instead. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ATTRIBUTES-directive.html#ATTRIBUTES-directive

Comment: Yeah, you're right about GCC, my brain for some reason ignored the bit about `!GCC&`

Answer (score 1):

In nvfortran, the `d` specifier to the `ignore_tkr` directive tells the compiler to ignore the presence or absence of the `device` attribute in argument matching when compiling CUDA Fortran codes.

Comment: Interesting possibility, but the code is probably ordinary Fortran, not CUDA Fortran. Else the other compilers would not be able to compile it. The Nvidia manual I linked in my answer does not mention this. Do you have a link describing this?

Comment: [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/compilers/fortran-cuda-interfaces/#iface-howto-doit) has:

A final aid, specific to NVIDIA, worth mentioning here is ignore_tkr (d), which ignores the device attribute of an actual argument during interface matching.

Comment: Thanks. This is not mentioned in the pdf manual "NVIDIA HPC COMPILERS REFERENCE GUIDE"